# Is there a jruby-on-rails idiom for detecting if you're running in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jruby, idioms, jrubyonrails

Checking `defined?(JRUBY_VERSION)` appears to be the most idiomatic way of determining whether you're running in jruby (c.f. [How can I tell if I'm running from JRuby vs. Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342535/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-from-jruby-vs-ruby), various FOSS jruby projects). Is there a similar idiom for determining whether you're running in Tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of an existing clearly established idiom, I'm going to propose `defined?($servlet_context)`. This would be defined in *any* servlet container, not just Tomcat in particular, but that may be preferable anyway.

Comment: Regarding your answer and subsequent flag [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337804/is-there-a-way-to-debug-a-jruby-on-rails-application-running-on-a-tomcat-server/8483552#8483552), you just deleted it. It won't be visible to anyone but you, moderators and 10k users. That's as good as it gets; SO doesn't really delete any content unless there is something really wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
public boolean isTomcat() {
    try {
      Class.forName("org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager");
      return true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look much like an idiom. I suspect there is something concise that would work both in jruby and in a vanilla ruby implementation. And probably something using the same "defined? SOME_CONSTANT" pattern.

Answer (score 0):

works in both mri and jruby

```
IN_TOMCAT = begin
   require 'org/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager'
   defined?(Java::org::apache::tomcat::InstanceManager)
rescue LoadError;end
```